# How to find all image locations on Android device?

Tags: android, image, location

How can I list all image directories on Android device? I need only directories, not image files. For example I want to receive:

```
/mnt/sdcard/DCIM
/mnt/sdcard/Downloads
/mnt/sdcard/Pictures
```

etc...

Thank you.

Comment: You can find your answer here https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-Multiple-file-Selector-Dialog

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html